# OpenCV edge enhancement

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, background-subtraction

I am performing background subtraction to obtain a moving car from a video as below ( Running average background modeling)

I am applying findContours() after this to draw a polygon around the car.

As you can see, the quality of the obtained output is not great. Is there any way I can enhance the edges of the car to make it more prominent and cut out the extraneous noise surrounding it. I tried performing morphological closing(dilate -> erode) to fill the gaps, but the output was not as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try using morphological operations the other way around -- instead of using closing to enhance the car silhouette, maybe you could try using opening to get rid of the surrounding noise? if you are then left just with an (imperfect) car on the picture, it might be easier to work with if it is left as the *only* object on the picture

Comment: Can you post a sample learned background, and then a sample frame with the car contained in it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill and far from a quick solution but Level Set Methods would be very suited to extract the presegmented car.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply background subtraction by using `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()`.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), isColor=False)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,180)

        outmask = out.apply(frame)
        output.write(outmask)

        cv2.imshow('original', frame)
        cv2.imshow('Motion Tracker', outmask)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break


output.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```